# How to get info about visable markers on android maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there a way to get info about displayed markers on android google maps(v2).
i have markers with different colors (each color represent category to be displayed on map) and I wonder if it possible to hide specific group from the current viewable map.

Answer (score 0):

I ran to this problem myself, couldn't find any reference in documentary for returning list of markers,
so I made a static class utility which holds the markers in an array.

Using Marker's getId() and remove() methods, [documented here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker) , I went to the specific marker according to Id and removed it from map.

Consider using separate arrays, holding each type of marker you have.
this will enable you to show the specific group you want by looping on the array and assigning markers like this:

```
 Marker marker = map.add(new MarkerOptions()
   .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
   .title("San Francisco")
   .snippet("Population: 776733"));
```

and the same thing for hiding marker (with remove method)

Comment: thanks for you replay. i also thought about this solution but in case i have a large set of markers i wanted to decrease my app memory footprint. if i wont find any solution i will use this one.

Comment: since we're in the same boat, I'll be glad to find more efficient way :D